# maintaining size and scrolling nested tables in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm building a relatively complicated page with some nested tables that should scroll.  Despite reading as much as I can on HTML tables, I don't seem to understand what's going.

See http://jsfiddle.net/JasonJSFiddle/etye72eg/

I want the top panel portion to always be 80% of the screen and the bottom to be 20% of the screen.

```
table.outer-table tr.outer-table-row1 {
    height:80%;
}
table.outer-table tr.outer-table-row2 {
    height:20%;
}
```

I was assuming by putting the 'overflow:auto' in the , this will make the nested tables scroll while maintaining the 80%/20% ratio of the outer table.  However, it seems to just push the cells out so top and bottom is 50% each.

How can I get the top portion to be 80% of the screen, and the nested table on the right to scroll and the bottom portion to be 20% and the nested table at the bottom to scroll?

Thanks!

Comment: Its complicated to do layouts that depend on tables and percentual sizes. Is it a requirement to use tables? Can't you change some of those tables by divs? Then you can use the div's table like behavior with the styles: display: table; display: table-row; and display: table-cell;  the just do float: left on the inner divs and its ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its usually not recomended to do layout with tables. Unless if you're working with mail marketing or some weird browser that doesn't support divs.

I like to do layout with divs using the css attributes:

```
display: table; 
display: table-row;
display: table-cell;
```

It gives the divs some tableish layout capabilities.

I have made an example for you with divs [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hqen9qyx/1/);

You can put the tables that are really necessary inside the divs. But to use percentual sizes, you have to make sure that the outer (outermost) element have a fixed size. (can be your div#main, or some other external wrapper of your layout).

Hope it helps

Comment: this is correct, but relies on the need for fixed sizes and I'm not sure that is a possibility, at least it's not mentioned. I'd upvote this answer if the OP agrees to use fixed sizes.

btw, for variable sizes he could just replace the percentages by vh and it would work no matter if fixed or not

Comment: The outer element must have a fixed size. It could be the #main div of his layout. Then, for the childs, he will have to calculate percentage by percentage, as they get sizes from their respective parents.